# What's the meaning of "at 91 yen to the dollar"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Context ([New York Times](http://travel.nytimes.com/2010/04/25/travel/25hours.html)),

> Edakuni Eiichi, the chef, turns out innovative dishes like daikon rolls stuffed with foie gras and sweet potatoes. The set 10-course meal, which changes monthly, is 3,680 yen (about $40 **at 91 yen to the dollar**).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The set 10-course meal, which changes monthly, is 3,680 yen (about $40 **at 91 yen to the dollar**).

In this sentence, *at 91 yen to the dollar* informs the reader that this is the rate used to calculate the conversion of 3,680, i.e. a dollar is worth 91 yen or 91 yen yields one dollar. If you divide 3680 by 91, you get approximately 40.

Here are similar hypothetical examples:

> - The set 10-course meal, which changes monthly, is 3,680 yen (about $37 at 99 yen to the dollar).
> - The set 10-course meal, which changes monthly, is 161 euro (about $85 at .53 euro to the dollar).

Including exchange rates in monetary conversions is important in any written work, as these rates are not constant.

Comment: 100 euro to the dollar? Hopefully we’re not getting there! Or else I’m moving abroad…

Comment: My example was ridiculous!! Hopefully that never happens. Editing to a saner scenario...

Comment: Don't panic, Google is telling me it should be "about 1.26 dollar to the euro" right now.

Answer (score 3):

*At 91 yen to the dollar* means *assuming that 91 yen is equal to a dollar*.  (3680 yen divided by 91 yen per dollar equals about 40 dollars.)

> The set 10-course meal, which changes monthly, is 3,680 yen (about $40, *assuming that 91 yen is equal to a dollar*).

However, the wording of the explanatory quote above is not as good as the wording in your example; the article's wording is more natural.

*Per* is also a common word which is used in a similar situation: *91 yen per dollar* is the same as *91 yen to the dollar*.

> The set 10-course meal, which changes monthly, is 3,680 yen (about $40, *at 91 yen per dollar*).

Comment: Thank you for giving structure of this phrase. Great help!